# How to get hosts from hosts file Ansible for Jenkins pipeline using the Groove script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, jenkins-groovy

I want to create a pipeline that can use the hostnames in the Ansible inventory file.
Path: ansible/inventories/preprod/hosts

```ini
[client-app]
client-app-preprod-01.aws
client-app-preprod-02.aws
client-app-preprod-03.aws
client-app-preprod-04.aws

[server-app]
server-app-preprod-01.aws
server-app-preprod-02.aws
server-app-preprod-03.aws
server-app-preprod-04.aws
```

I created a script that works functionally, but uses a list of hosts from itself (hardcode).
Groovy Script:

```
if (ENVIRONMENT=="preprod") {
    if (SERVICE=="client-app") {
        hostsList = ['client-app-preprod-01.aws','client-app-preprod-02.aws','client-app-preprod-03.aws','client-app-preprod-04.aws']
        } else {
        hostsList =  ['server-app-preprod-01.aws','server-app-preprod-02.aws','server-app-preprod-03.aws','server-app-preprod-04.aws']
    }
}
return hostsList
```

but I can't find a solution to create a script that can read hosts from the Ansible repository and inventory file.
I would be grateful for any information that can help me write this script. Courses, books, examples and more.

In addition, the pipeline should look like this:

[image: screenshot Jenkins PipeLine]

Comment: This is a requirement, not a question. SO is a place to ask questions and provide answers about programming related issues, not a developer marketplace to ask to write code for you. Please [edit] your question, adding at the very least what you have tried so far to attempt fullfiling your requirement. Before you start editing you'll probably want to read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the description.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function you can use to process the Inventory file and get the host entries.

```
def getHostList(def appName, def filePath) {

    def hosts = []
    def content = readFile(file: filePath)
    def startCollect = false
    for(def line : content.split('\n')) {
        if(line.contains("["+ appName +"]")){ // This is a starting point of host entries
            startCollect = true
            continue
        } else if(startCollect) {
            if(!line.allWhitespace && !line.contains('[')){
                hosts.add(line.trim())
            } else {
                break
            }
        } 
    }
    return hosts
}
```

You can call this function like below.

```
def hosts = getHostList("client-app", "ansible/inventories/preprod/hosts")
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr!
In fact, the task is a little more difficult. The file is on GitHub.
The bitbucket solution doesn't work.
def pvRepoUrl = "<link>"
def authString = "<user>:<password>".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def conn = pvRepoUrl.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
Is there a solution for GitHub?

Comment: @Vitaliy It's best to create a new SO question for this.

Comment: @Vitaliy please check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73674076/2627018